# How to count for each ID, how many of each Type of outcomes(1,2,3) has that ID diagnosised?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have tried many times but i have no idea how to group the answer for each technician for each diagnosis outcome (Only three types 1,2,3) that they have? (For example, how many diagnosis outcome 1 did technicianID 54 have .)

I try to put in the count function but it is not works.Could someone give me some idea in SQL?

It is what i found in the database.

```
TechnicianID FirstName
------------ -------------
54           Wayne

TechnicianID DiagnosisOutcomeID
------------ ------------------
54           1
54           2
54           1
54           3

The Result should be
TechnicianID FirstName    DiagnosisOutcome=1    DiagnosisOutcome=2 DiagnosisOutcome=3
------------ -------------
54           Wayne
```

ThankYou

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not mentioned any RDBMS, the query below will work on many RDBMS,

```
SELECT  a.TechnicianID,
        a.FirstName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.DiagnosisOutcomeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DiagnosisOutcomeID1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.DiagnosisOutcomeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DiagnosisOutcomeID2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.DiagnosisOutcomeID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DiagnosisOutcomeID3
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.TechnicianID = b.TechnicianID 
GROUP   BY a.TechnicianID, a.FirstName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ace8/1)

If you are using `RDBMS` that supports `PIVOT` function,

```
SELECT  TechnicianID, 
        FirstName,
        DiagnosisOutcomeID1,
        DiagnosisOutcomeID2,
        DiagnosisOutcomeID3
FROM
(
    SELECT  a.TechnicianID,
            a.FirstName,
            'DiagnosisOutcomeID' + CAST(b.DiagnosisOutcomeID AS VARCHAR(5)) AS DiagnosisOutcomeID
    FROM    Table1 a
            INNER JOIN Table2 b
                ON a.TechnicianID = b.TechnicianID 
) data
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(DiagnosisOutcomeID)
    FOR DiagnosisOutcomeID IN (DiagnosisOutcomeID1,DiagnosisOutcomeID2,DiagnosisOutcomeID3)
) pvt
ORDER BY TechnicianID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b362b/5)

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE` statement is what you need.

Have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71150/2)

```
SELECT T.FirstName
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN DiagnosisOutcomeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OUTCOME1
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN DiagnosisOutcomeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OUTCOME2
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN DiagnosisOutcomeID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OUTCOME3
FROM   Tech T
INNER JOIN
       Diagnosis D
ON     T.TechnicianID = D.TechnicianID
GROUP BY
       T.FirstName
```